# Open new colorbox window over an iframe

Tags: jquery, window, colorbox, parent

I have my parent link setup like so:

```
    $(".ajax").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:"470px", innerHeight:"500px"});
```

This will open the first iframe, inside that parent iframe I have links. Currently these links load the new content in the parent Colorbox window without resizing or anything. Thats fine, but I need to load another window over the parent colorbox as the content on window 2 needs less space (200px width instead of the parent 470px)

how can this be achieved? So far I have tried:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.open_page2').colorbox({
        width:"704px",
        height:"800px",
        iframe:true,
        scrolling: false,
        overlayClose: false,
        photo: false,
        opacity: 0.6
    }); 
     });
```

with no luck. Also be reminded that the new window needs to open from a href link.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I have to do the same, and I can't get it working.